Hiding image parent div
I am setting up a Bootstrap carousel. I wrote the HTML for 20 images, and the number of images changes weekly. The image names are Pic001, Pic002, etc. How do I hide the image's parent div that has an error? (no image to be found, for that HTML)


$(document).ready(function() {
  $("img").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    this.onerror = function() {
      $(this).parent().hide();
    };
  });
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel-item" id="Slide010">Hide this
  <img class="d-block w-100" src="/sites/Yo/Flyers/Pic010.jpg" alt="Slide10" />
</div>




You are too late when you execute the code. All load or error event handlers on the images have already run.
Instead have a dummy image (blank or such).
Use a data attribute, load the image from the data attribute which then can trigger the error


$(function() {
    let carousel;
    const initCarousel = () => {
      const $slides = $('#myCarousel').find('.carousel-item')
      if ($slides.length > 0) {
        $slides.eq(0).addClass('active'); // make the first image active
        carousel = new bootstrap.Carousel('#myCarousel');
      }  
    }  
  // get the urls
  const imgs = Array.from({ length: 10}).map((_, i) => `https://placehold.co/600x400?text=Slide+${i+1}`); 
  imgs[3] = ''; // the 4th one does not exist.
  imgCount = imgs.length - 1;
  // generate the slides
  $('.carousel-inner').html(imgs.map((img, i) => `<div class="carousel-item"><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400?text=dummy" data-src="${imgs[i]}" class="d-block w-100" alt="${i}"></div>`).join(''));
    // load the images
    $("img").each(function(i) {
      $(this).on('error', function() {
        $(this).closest('.carousel-item').remove();
        imgCount--;
        if (imgCount === 0) initCarousel()
      });
      $(this).on('load', function() {
        imgCount--;
        if (imgCount === 0) initCarousel()
      });
      this.src = this.dataset.src;

    });
  });
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-interval="3000" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
  </div>
</div>



Alternatively preload the images and create the carousel from the list of images that worked

Sweet, Thank you. It worked like a charm. Sorry to bother you again. I was trying for it to go to the next carousel-item. I can't get it to work
$(function() {   $("img").each(function() {     this.onerror = function() {       $(this).closest('.carousel-item').hide();     $('.carousel').carousel('next');     };     this.src = this.dataset.src;   }); });

I updated the script to remove the slide if there is no image

PS: Please visit this help page
